# I am new to Lua scripting language and I am getting the following error while connecting it to the local redis server

Tags: redis, lua

I am new to Lua scripting language and I am getting the following error while connecting it to the local redis server

> ERR user_script:2: Script attempted to access nonexistent global variable 'require
> ' script: a97a3c34edbccf96c1b21c2f604411d895e2a452, on @user_script:2.

Here is my code

```
local redis = require "redis"
local csv = require "csv"
```

Comment: Here is my full code.   local redis = require "redis"
local csv = require "csv"

-- Connect to the Redis server
local client = redis.connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)

-- Read the CSV file
local file = io.open("mappables.csv", "r")
local records = {}
for fields in csv.lines(file) do
  table.insert(records, fields)
end
file:close()

-- Insert the data into Redis
for i, fields in ipairs(records) do
  local key, value = fields[1], fields[2]
  client:set(key, value)
end

-- Close the Redis connection
client:quit()

Comment: the error would appear to indicate `require` does not exist in your enviorment

Comment: I tried to add it through luarocks but still getting the error @nifim

Comment: Do you have a link that I follow?

Comment: `require` is a stock lua function, it can often be removed to sandbox an environment and prevent you from loading some code, you would need to recreate it's functionality if you have access to the functions required to do that, such as some variant of `load` to compile a lua file to executable byte code